# Website wont scroll when browser is minimised size even though I have media queries set up? - CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries, styled-components

I've just spent ages sorting out all my media queries for different screen sizes, however when I just minimize my browser on laptop to take up half of screen I can see that the positioning for my content looks right but only get half the screen no option to scroll vertically which is what I want.

I'm pretty sure it is to do with position: relative in Container as when I take this off I can scroll but then all the content on screen is out of place. Does anyone know the root of my problem and how to fix this, been unsuccessful so far.

Code is below, I have also made a code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bose-wrsym?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675) however I don't really trust it as it seems to be adding scrolls (vertical and horizontal) by default when they don't show when I have my react app on my localhost browser.

(I'm using React and styled components to apply the css)

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import lantern from '../src/Assets/lantern.svg'
import wok from '../src/Assets/wok.svg'
import edges from '../src/Assets/edges.svg';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

function App() {
  return (
  
    <Container>
      <Img />
      <HalfCircle />
      <HalfCircle1 />
      <Title>
        Authentic Asian Cuisine Delivered Straight To Your Door!
      </Title>
      <Wok/>
      {/* <Edges/> */}
      <HomeButton/>
      <HomeButtonText>
        Order Now!
      </HomeButtonText>
    </Container>

    
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
 
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #FDFAF6;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  
`;

const Img = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${lantern});
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 314px;
  height: 328px;
  left: 100px;
  top: -11px;

  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 334px;
    height: 358px;
    left: 60px;
    top: -11px;
  }

  /* Tablet (Ipad) */
  @media (max-width: 768px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 274px;
    height: 298px;
    left: 5 0px;
    top: -11px;
  }

  /* Large Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 plus) */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 176px;
    left: 14px;
    top: -11px;
  }
  /* Medium Phone (Iphone 6/7/8) */
  @media (max-width: 376px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 155px;
    height: 166px;
    left: 14px;
    top: -11px;
  }
  /* Small Phone (Iphone 5/SE) */
  @media (max-width: 320px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 155px;
    height: 146px;
    left: 8px;
    top: -11px;
  }
  
`

const HalfCircle = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  height: 370px;
  left: 1310px;
  top: -136px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 4px 7px #d1d9d9;
  background: #E4EFE7;

  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 460px;
    left: 760px;
    top: -136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px #d1d9d9;
    background: #E4EFE7;
  }

  /* Tablet (Ipad) */
  @media (max-width: 768px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 430px;
    height: 390px;
    left: 600px;
    top: -136px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 4px 7px #d1d9d9;
    background: #E4EFE7;
  }

  /* Large Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 Plus) */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 269px;
    left: 253px;
    top: -116px;

    background: #E4EFE7;
  }
  /* Medium Phone (Iphone 6/7/8) */
  @media (max-width: 376px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 249px;
    left: 253px;
    top: -116px;

    background: #E4EFE7;
  }

  
  /* Small Phone (Iphone 5/SE) */
  @media (max-width: 320px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 239px;
    left: 208px;
    top: -116px;

    background: #E4EFE7;
  }
  /* Extra Small Device (Galaxy Fold) */
  @media (max-width: 280px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 299px;
    height: 249px;
    left: 203px;
    top: -116px;

    background: #E4EFE7;
  }


`

const HalfCircle1 = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  height: 370px;
  left: -217px;
  top: 507px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 8px 5px #d1d9d9;

  background: #E4EFE7;

  /* Large Tablet */
  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    display: none;
  }
  /* Tablet */
  @media (max-width: 768px){
    display: none;
  }

  /* Mobile */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    display: none;
  }
`
const Title = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 553px;
  height: 153px;
  left: 505px;
  top: 148px;

  font-family: Rosario;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;

  color: #000000;

  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 672px;
    height: 141px;
    left: 194px;
    top: 404px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 44px;
    line-height: 56px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 472px;
    height: 141px;
    left: 154px;
    top: 304px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Large Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 Plus) */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 352px;
    height: 121px;
    left: 24px;
    top: 224px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Medium Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 ) */
  @media (max-width: 376px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 352px;
    height: 121px;
    left: 22px;
    top: 204px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Small Phone (Iphone 5/SE) */
  @media (max-width: 320px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 292px;
    height: 121px;
    left: 12px;
    top: 184px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /*Extra Small Device (Galaxy Fold) */
  @media (max-width: 280px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 272px;
    height: 121px;
    left: 8px;
    top: 184px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }
`

const Wok = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${wok});
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 434px;
  height: 434px;
  left: 867px;
  top: 328px;

  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    left: 295px;
    top: 845px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    left: 205px;
    top: 645px;
  }

  /* Large Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 Plus) */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 75px;
    top: 465px;
  }
  /* Medium Phone (Iphone 6/7/8) */
  @media (max-width: 376px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 217px;
    left: 75px;
    top: 445px;
  }

  /* Small Phone (Iphone 5/SE) */
  @media (max-width: 320px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 210px;
    height: 207px;
    left: 49px;
    top: 385px;

  }

  /* Extra Small Device (Galaxy Fold) */
  @media (max-width: 280px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 210px;
    height: 207px;
    left: 39px;
    top: 385px;
  }
`
const Edges = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${edges});
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 205px;
  height: 205px;
  left: 1376px;
  top: 563px;
`
const HomeButton = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 369px;
  height: 113px;
  left: 345px;
  top: 369px;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px #d1d9d9;
  background: #E4EFE7;
  border-radius: 25px;

  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 381px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 327px;
    top: 600px;
    box-shadow: 4px 10px #d1d9d9;
    background: #E4EFE7;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 301px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 227px;
    top: 485px;
    box-shadow: 2px 7px #d1d9d9;
    background: #E4EFE7;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  /* Large Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 Plus) */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    position: absolute;
    

    width: 221px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 87px;
    top: 335px;
    box-shadow: 2px 7px #d1d9d9;

    background: #E4EFE7;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  
  /* Medium Phone (Iphone 6/7/8) */
  @media (max-width: 376px){
    position: absolute;
    

    width: 221px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 75px;
    top: 325px;
    box-shadow: 2px 7px #d1d9d9;

    background: #E4EFE7;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  /* Small Phone (Iphone 5/SE) */
  @media (max-width: 320px){
    position: absolute;
    

    width: 221px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 42px;
    top: 285px;
    box-shadow: 2px 7px #d1d9d9;

    background: #E4EFE7;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  /* Extra Small Device (Galaxy Fold) */
  @media (max-width: 280px){
    position: absolute;
    

    width: 221px;
    height: 57px;
    left: 34px;
    top: 285px;
    box-shadow: 2px 7px #d1d9d9;

    background: #E4EFE7;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
`

const HomeButtonText = styled.div`
 position: absolute;
  width: 241px;
  height: 46px;
  left: 402px;
  top: 403px;

  

  font-family: Rosario;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;

  color: #000000;

  @media (max-width: 1024px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 31px;
    left: 426px;
    top: 635px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }
  /* Tablet */
  @media (max-width: 768px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 31px;
    left: 286px;
    top: 511px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Large Phone (Iphone 6/7/8 Plus) */
  @media (max-width: 576px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 31px;
    left: 106px;
    top: 349px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Medium Phone (Iphone 6/7/8) */
  @media (max-width: 376px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 31px;
    left: 94px;
    top: 339px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Small Phone (Iphone 5/SE) */
  @media (max-width: 320px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 31px;
    left: 61px;
    top: 299px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }

  /* Extra Small Device (Galaxy Fold) */
  @media (max-width: 280px){
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 31px;
    left: 53px;
    top: 299px;

    font-family: Rosario;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
  }
`
export default App;
```

Comment: The CodeSandbox is an empty starter project, no example code of yours.

Comment: Hmm okay will try and sort that link worked before lemme check it now

Comment: Shows up for me, first time I have made one though so maybe I am not saving somewhere I am suppose to?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-glitter-morom try this

Comment: Same empty starter project, at least on my end. Maybe someone else has more luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added `overflow: hidden;` in your `Container`. So you need to remove `overflow: hidden` from your container.

```
const Container = styled.div`
 
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #FDFAF6;
  /* overflow: hidden;  <-- comment or remove this */  
`;
```

Demo [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mendel-889iq?file=/src/App.js):

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the issue if though I need the overflow to be hidden as its part of the deisgn with the half circles I need half of it to be cut off. If I then delete overflow hidden the scrolls go vertically and horizontally to where the full shapes are so actually outside of the website/design if that makes sense?

Comment: You could put the half cirlces into another wrapper container, that is the first child of the main container, has height and width set to 100% and `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Here is a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-grothendieck-tsgjd?file=/src/App.js) of mic's sandbox with a possible Circle-Wrapper solution

Comment: Thanks for recommendation Tino will try this out now! btw the sandbox doesn't have the circle wrapper solution in it when I go to the link

Comment: Tried the wrapper solution but unfortunately it just gives same result as removing overflow: hidden from Container

Comment: OK, so codesandbox keeps messing with us :D
I'll post the CircleWrapper Solution in a separate answer. I hope, this works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232984/discussion-between-tino-and-micst).

Answer (score 0):

**Circle-Wrapper**

You could put the half cirlces into another wrapper container, that is the first child of the main container, has height and width set to 100% and `overflow: hidden`

The code is reduced to the relevant parts:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Img />
      <CirleWrapper>
        <HalfCircle />
        <HalfCircle1 />
      </CirleWrapper>
      <Title>Authentic Asian Cuisine Delivered Straight To Your Door!</Title>
      <Wok />
      {/* <Edges/> */}
      <HomeButton />
      <HomeButtonText>Order Now!</HomeButtonText>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #fdfaf6;
`;

const CirleWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

[...]

const HalfCircle = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  height: 370px;
  left: 1310px;
  top: -136px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 4px 7px #d1d9d9;
  background: #e4efe7;

  @media (max-width: 1024px) {

  [...]
```